# Generate relation between two parties from the relation table using R

Tags: r

I have a relational table that contains a list of relations:

```
Party_A     Party_B
a           b
c           a
d           b
b           e
...
```

You can think of this table contains the information of (directed: direction is from Party_A to Party_B) edges in a graph.

I want some packages that can convert this table into a graph model that supports the following query:
Find two parties that are most similar with each other, where similarity is defined as having most common input edges.

Any packages in R that can help me do this? Thank you.

Comment: You can check `library(igraph)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could approach it (using [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)):

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="source     target
a           b
c           b
a           e
c           e
f           g
h           i
a           i
c           i")
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
m <- t(as_adjacency_matrix(g, sparse = F))
d <- dist(m[rowSums(m)>0, ], method = "binary")

dm <- as.matrix(d); dm[upper.tri(dm, T)] <- NA
idx <- which(dm == min(dm, na.rm=T), T)
cbind(rownames(dm)[idx[, "row"]], colnames(dm)[idx[, "col"]])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "e"  "b"
```

To visualize the distances in a dendrogram:

```
hc <- hclust(d)
plot(hc)
```

[image]

Adjust the distance measure to your needs.